# AOS Library not working except for on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate-on-scroll

I am building a website in which a div needs to slide in from the left to the right when it is scrolled into view. I am using the [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) library to animate it, but it is not working unless I scroll the element into view, and then refresh the tab.

Here's my HTML's head:

```html
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
```

And my body content:

```
    <div class="aos-item top" data-aos="slide-right">
        <h3><em>Header Here</em></h3>
            <p>
                <big>
                    Content Here.
                </big>
            </p>
    </div>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Or is it the library? If it is the library, are there any good alternatives?

Comment: Is the code in your question in your `<body>`?  Stylesheets should go in the `<head>`

Comment: @Amy The stylesheet <link> is located in the <head>. I just put it at the beginning so that you can see how I linked to it. The rest is located in the body.

Comment: The JS script tag is missing.

Comment: I made a mistake when coping and pasting. I edited my question. Sry.