# UseEffect Not Triggering Until I Refresh For AOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, aos.js

I could not find an answer here [AOS Library not working except for on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863033/aos-library-not-working-except-for-on-refresh)

I am making a react app and wanted to use AOS for animating https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/.

I have a functional component with this code

```
import AOS from 'aos';
import 'aos/dist/aos.css';


export default function Portfolio() {

  useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 1000
    });
    AOS.refresh();
  }, []);

return(
 <span className="bumper">Projects </span>
      
      <div data-aos="fade-in">
      <h3>  Hello! </h3>
      </div>
)
```

When I first load the page, the screen only says "Projects", and there is no "Hello!", but when I edit the "Hello!" to "Hi!" and React auto-refreshes I see the animation come in.

What is possibly happening here?

I am in the React Dev environment

```
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "aos": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
```

Comment: From a quick google search I see that ```aos.refresh()``` could cancel durations, could you try without ?

Comment: Is the closing `h2` tag there for a reason?

Comment: No sorry, I'll edit the h2 out.

Comment: The result is the same, with the `AOS.refresh()` edited out. Hmmm

Comment: You might try putting a `setTimeout` around the AOS calls, just in case has to wait for something to be ready. You also might try `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`. I'm not familiar with AOS, but it seems like it might affect the DOM?

Comment: AOS=animation on scroll, it's just to animate when you scroll to an element.

`useLayoutEffect` gives the same response as `useEffect`, `setTimeout` did not work around AOS.refresh either. Thank you for the ideas though

Answer (score 0):

React V18 added a rerender for useEffect Hook. So now it's rerendering twice on strict mode, enabled. There are two ways to tackle this. Either you disable strict mode (Which I totally don't recommend), or you undo what happens on the first render from happening by returning a callback that works on unmounting the component.

```html
useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 1000
    });
    AOS.refresh();
return () => {
//Kill your animation not sure of the syntax for AOS. 
AOS.kill()
//Or 
AOS.refresh()
}
  }, []);
```

Comment: I just tried this on my react app 

  useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init();
    return () => {
      AOS.refresh();
    };
  }, []);

It worked fine. Firstly it was juts like yours. It wasn't working unless you refresh. Now it works from the first render